# find + how to print the file name when grep is matched

Tags: linux, awk, sed, find, xml

the following useful find command , print the value from Name tag

```
find /tmp -type f -name '*.xml' -exec grep -o -P '(?<=<Name>).*(?=</Name>)' {} \;
```

the problem is in case we have couple xml files under /tmp then we never know which xml file have the Name tag

or in other words this find syntax will print the value of Name

**but without the xml file name**

please advice how to print the file name when grep matched the:

```
(?<=<Name>).*(?=</Name>)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To use a proper XML parser (here I use `xmlstarlet`) to extract the values of all `Name` nodes in all XML files that have a `.xml` filename suffix in or under `/tmp`:

```
find /tmp -type f -name '*.xml' -exec xmlstarlet sel -t -v '//Name' -nl {} +
```

This does *not* require that the `<Name>` opening tag and the corresponding `</Name>` closing tag are on the same line, nor does it require that the `Name` node has no attributes, like your `grep` command does.

To output a bit more information with `xmlstarlet`, like the filename that is currently being processed, and to only do that if the file actually has a `Name` node, replace the `xmlstarlet` invocation in the `find` command above with

```bsh
xmlstarlet sel -t -i '//Name' -o '### ' -f -o ':' -nl -v '//Name' -nl
```

This outputs the pathname of the XML file, prefixed by `###`  and suffixed by `:` and a newline, but only if the file contains a `Name` node.  After that comes the values of each `Name` node in the document.

---

Using `grep`:

`grep` will always output the filename of the file containing the match if more than one file is given on the command line. If you only pass it one file, no filename will be printed.

To force always printing the filename along with the actual match, add `/dev/null` as an extra file to grep in:

```
find /tmp -type f -name '*.xml' -exec grep -o -P '(?<=<Name>).*(?=</Name>)' {} /dev/null \;
```

Or, for potentially fewer invocations of `grep`, use `find -exec grep ... {} +` instead:

```
find /tmp -type f -name '*.xml' -exec grep -o -P '(?<=<Name>).*(?=</Name>)' /dev/null {} +
```

At least GNU `grep` as well as `grep` on OpenBSD and FreeBSD also support the `-H` flag to always print the filename, even if only one file is given. Since you used `grep -P`, you're probably using GNU `grep` anyway.

Answer (score 3):

You simply give greps  "-H" parameter, then the filename will always be printed, even if there is only one file to grep from (as in your case).

Comment: `-H` is an extension to the standard `grep` supported by GNU `grep` and a few other implementations.

Comment: On linux, I suppose the chances that the OP is using GNU grep, are quite high.

Answer (score 1):

Note, `grep` is not the right tool for parsing xml/html files(documents) and won't give a robust and solid solution. Use a "proper" xml/html parsers like **`xmlstarlet`**:

```
find /tmp -type f -name '*.xml' -exec xmlstarlet sel -t -m "//Name" -f -n {} \;
```

- `xmlstarlet sel -t -m "//Name" -f -n` - will print input file name (ensured by option `-f`) only if input xml document matches (`-m`) XPATH expression `"//Name"`

Comment: xmlstarlet not installed on my machine can you change it to xmllint

Comment: I guess option to do the same approach with xmlinit cant be done?

Comment: @yael, `xmllint` is not able to print its input filename as the only output (only within a debug-trace). It's doable and  I have such solution but it requires a subshell invocation, just a little bit longer than the above approach. So if you need it - I have it

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind that the filename is printed after the found lines, there's always finds "-print" option:

```
find /tmp -type f -name '*.xml' -exec grep -o -P '(?<=<Name>).*(?=</Name>)' {} \; -print
```